# Apparent patterns in ratios of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was plotting the values of $\frac{P(n+1)}{P(n)+2}$, where $P(n)$ is the nth prime number. I noticed very easily that the values seem to belong very nicely to a set of "trajectories". They clearly cannot have arbitrarily values.

Of course all these trajectories are decreasing and tend to $1$, except the trajectory for twin primes, which is, of course, $1$.

I also made a rough estimate that they can be estimated with functions of the form $1+a/x^b$, the first trajectory above constant $1$ is close to $1+1.1/x^{1.19}$.

Is there more info on these trajectories? Given $n$ is smaller than some number, how many trajectories there are in total? By counting from the graph, I would say, if $n<10,000$, there are about 27 trajectories (ie.about 27 different curves where the values fit).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trajectories are simply the curves $1 + \frac{2k}{x \log x} \approx 1 + \frac{2k}{P(\lfloor x\rfloor)}$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.  Since $P(n+1)-P(n)$ tends to be extremely small compared to $n$, it takes the same (even) values quite often, and your function is nothing more than $1 + \frac{P(n+1)-P(n)-2}{P(n)+2}$.

Comment: How do you know the trajectories are equal to $1+\frac{2k}{x \log x}?$

Comment: @Valtteri Are you unfamiliar with the Prime Number Theorem, or are you simply asking for a more formal proof?

Comment: Quite unfamiliar, I must confess. It states that $\pi (x)$ is asymptotically $x/Log(x)$?

Comment: @Valtteri Yup, that's right.  If you calculate an approximate inverse function of $x/\log x$ you'll find that it implies that the $n$th prime $P(n)$ is asymptotically $n \log n$.  Better approximations are possible but it's still true that $P(n)/(n\log n) \to 1$.

Comment: So, are you saying that the trajectories are asymptotically $1+2k/(x \log x)$ for some $k$? Or that $P(n+1)/(2 + P(n))$ is equal to $1+2k/(x \log x)$ for some $k$?

Comment: @Valtteri Yes, they are asymptotically $1 + 2k/(x\log x)$.  The exact value of $P(n+1)/(2+P(n))$ is equal to $1 + 2k/(2+P(n))$ for some $k$, and $2 + P(n)$ is close to $n \log n$ for large enough $n$.  The $n$ in your graph are perhaps a bit too small for this approximation to fit perfectly, but this is strictly a "small number phenomenon".

Comment: Ah, I see, I am content, thank you.